# Include Custom Details While Exporting Rad Grid to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, export-to-excel, radgrid

I am using telerik rad grid. It provides the functionality to [export grid data into excel](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/exporting/excel-export/defaultcs.aspx). I would like to do some modification while this data is getting exported.

I want to include company details ( i.e logo and some other custom details which are not there in rad grid ) in the exported file.

Is there any possibility of doing this with rad grid export function. Something like overriding the function where i can write these custom data to exported excel file ?

What is the best way to do this ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: 
http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-export-to-excel-and-add-extra-information#pktx029dKk2yBlBGE07Msw

The idea is to add some simple HTML in the grid before calling the export method:

Let's copy the code from the linked thread :)

```
  RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span><br/>Description: Data selected using dates between 1 Jan 2011 to 1 Sep 2011</span>"));
  RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Caption = "<span><br/>Exported by: John Smith</span>";
  RadGrid1.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
  RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = false;
  RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this out. But i guess this will make changes in the UI as well. right ?

Comment: thanks. This worked very well with a small change. I have edited your answer to make RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;.